# How to set the JMSCorrelationID and correlate with JMSMessageID with a Camel client and a IBMMQ broker

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq, camel-jms

I have a Camel client using the JMS Component to connect with IBMMQ.

I need to

- Send a JMSCorrelationID with a fixed value.
- Correlate the Reply message by JMSMessageID.

My configuration is:

```
.setHeader("CamelJmsDestinationName", "queue:///requestQueue.AQ?targetClient=1")
.setHeader("JMSCorrelationID", "SomeValue")
.to("jms:queue:requestQueue.AQ?useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true&replyTo=ResponseQueue")
```

The issue is that JMSCorrelationID is null when useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true

```
  JMSMessageID:     ID:c3e2d840d8d4e3f14040404040404040d95c7873193bef06
  JMSTimestamp:     1614870096440
  JMSCorrelationID: null
```

When useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=false the JMSCorrelationID is set as intended, but I get a timeout on correlation. How to use both?

Comment: Why are you setting `targetClient=1`? This instructs IBM MQ to removes the MQ RFH2 header containing JMS headers.

Comment: There is Cobol programm on the other side which needs the message as MQStr and cannot handle MQ RFh2

Answer (score 1):

As a way around the issue I made the following changes to the .to() endpoint options:

- exchangePattern=InOnly
- includeSentJMSMessageID=true

Then the message is sent with a JMSCorrelationID, but without waiting on the reply. Thereafter I set a pollEnrich() dynamically with a simple expression using the JMSMessageID created by the broker which is filtered by a JMS Selector:

- selector=JMSMessageID='${header.JMSMessageID}

The Camel route:

```
.setHeader("CamelJmsDestinationName", "queue:///requestQueue.AQ?targetClient=1")
.setHeader("JMSCorrelationID", "SomeValue")
.to("jms://RequestQueue?useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=false&exchangePattern=InOnly&replyTo=ReplyQueue&includeSentJMSMessageID=true")
.pollEnrich().simple("jms://ReplyQueue?selector=JMSMessageID='${header.JMSMessageID}').timeout(20000)
.log("${body}")
```